Editing fraction design in nomencl package in LaTeX
first time question, but longtime user of all the great answers here.
I make it simple. (MWE down below, using Overleaf with pdflatex compiler)
I want to use a horizontal fraction design in my nomenclature (with the option of showing the formula), when I reference formulas and units instead of the diagonal fraction. The siunitx package comes with the option to do that, by either changing the option in the package directly to per-mode = fraction or by changing it at the implementation.
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{siunitx} %could be changed to \usepackage[per-mode = fraction]{siunitx}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[nomentbl]{nomencl} %changes to table format for nomencl

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
    
    heres some nomenclature for the Speed of Light in a Vacuum \(c\)

    \nomenclature{\(c\)}{Speed of light in a vacuum}{\unit[per-mode = fraction]{\meter\per\second}}{}
    
    \unit[per-mode = fraction]{\meter\per\second}
    %this line is only present to show the difference between the fraction in the nomencl environment and by standing on its own, using the same command

    \printnomenclature

\end{document}

Next come the two pictures of how it shows on the page:

and in the nomenclature:

I tried using \si instead of \unit, I tried using the option directly in the package declaration instead, but nothing seems to work. Since the option works without being implemented in the nomencl-package (compare the two pictures, using the same command for the fraction), I assume that the nomencl-package is somehow blocking or changing it, but I can't wrap my head around it when checking the documentation on CTAN. In 2.8 and 2.9 of the nomencl-package documentation, they outline some options on how to edit the nomenclature, but nothing of that seems (to me) to solve my problem. If anyone can make that work, I would really appreciate this.
EDIT:
Until now, I created my own nomenclature by using a table and the mathmode environment. Leaving aside any other design questions (hline etc.), it looked like this (horizontal fraction):


Welcome. // Can you please add a sketch or mockup how you want the result to be? Thank you

@MS-SPO Inserted a picture of my previous used nomenclature made with a table. In mathmode, fractions will be horizontal instead of diagonal, which is what I prefer, but somehow can't implement with the nomencl-package.

From what I can see, nomencl is defining that the third argument here is a unit (argument to \unit): as such, you'll need to set options outside of that area.

Just don't use \unit: the nomentbl options automatically adds it. See page 13 of the manual.
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[per-mode = fraction]{siunitx}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[nomentbl]{nomencl} %changes to table format for nomencl

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
    
Here's some nomenclature for the Speed of Light in a Vacuum \(c\)

\nomenclature{\(c\)}{Speed of light in a vacuum}{\meter\per\second}{}

\unit{\meter\per\second}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}

I used a trick for printing everything on the same page, but it's not necessary to see it.

The produced .nls file contains
\begin{thenomenclature} 
\nomgroup{A}
  \item &{\(c\)}&\begingroup Speed of light in a vacuum\endgroup &\unit {\meter\per\second}&\begingroup \endgroup &\begingroup \nomeqref {0.0}\nompageref{1}

\end{thenomenclature}


Of all the things I tried and read, I didn't try or read that. Thanks, works perfectly.

As nomencl treats the thrid argument as a unit argument, one needs to set up the appearance outside of the argument. For example
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[]{siunitx}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[nomentbl]{nomencl}

\DeclareSIUnit[per-mode = fraction]{\velocityunit}{\meter\per\second}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
    
    heres some nomenclature for the Speed of Light in a Vacuum \(c\)

    \nomenclature{\(c\)}{Speed of light in a vacuum}{\velocityunit}{}
    
    
    \unit{\velocityunit}
    
    \printnomenclature

\end{document}


one could delete the inputenc line ...

This does work design-related as intended, thank you. But it seems I would have to use \DeclareSIUnit  for every unit I plan to use? In my case, this would not really reduce the work load I hoped by automating the nomenclature with the package.

@HenningIrmler Well ideally you set unit appearance globally, so for example \sisetup{per-mode = fraction} in the preamble. But your example implied you are using a non-standard setting just for the units of the speed of light.
